# Full screen issue with java.awt.Window

Tags: java, java-me, awt

I have developed a J2ME app using `java.awt.Window` as I want a full screen without any status and title bars on top.

The problem I am facing is: the first screen is displayed in full screen but from then on all the screens displayed have a white strip appearing at the bottom of the screen.
I have used `setBounds(0,0,320,240)` (my device dimensions) but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has answered this.I would like to tell how I fixed this.When designing the frame in netbeans, I specified the coordinates of 
setbounds(0,0,345,240); 
I know it is kind of a patch and not a solution, but that worked.. and it looks good on the device :)